# How to compare lists of words and strings, then to print full string that contains word using python?

Tags: python, string, list

Compare 2 lists in python. First list contain words and second list with strings/lines. If any word in list1 is found in list2 (strings), then print full matched string/lines.

```
list1=["watch","hour","time"]

list2=["new watch rolex","time","digital watch","minutes hour second"]
```

Output:

```
new watch rolex,time,digital watch,minutes hour second
```

Comment: Seems pretty basic, you should try it first yourself. If you do not know how, I would suggest - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Comment: Your example doesn't print `time` though it's in list 2 - is that intentional?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you want to check if a string i contains string j, you can do it using i in j. Then comes the part how do you want the output actually. What my approach was to go through the list1 and for each of them go though the list2 and check if element of list2 contains the element of list1. If contains then i checked if they are equal or not. If equal i skipped them. Otherwise i have printed the element of list2.

As @mathius indicated, my code will print the same element of list2 more than once. I didn't handle that because to me, post maker didn't want that. Look forward to your opinion. Here is my code:

```
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i in j and i != j:
            print j
```

Comment: No need for range. -1

Comment: No explanation and the output doesn't meet the requirement

Comment: Try your code with a `list2` value of `['watch the hour']`.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque still no explanation

Comment: Why are you looping over `list1` in the outer loop and `list2` in the inner loop, rather than the other way around?

Comment: `i is not j` is wrong, should be `i != j`

Comment: @vaultah i is not j works fine, why it is wrong? bad practice?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque: Try this: `a='test';b='te';b+='st';print a==b,a is b`. The `is` operator tests if two variables refer to the same object. Sometimes it appears to work when comparing strings for equality due to string interning - i.e. Python "recycles" the same object for short strings. But you can't rely on it, as my example shows.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque you are getting downvotes because you have just answered with code try adding explanation and run the code against given OP sample and print the output

Comment: @PM2Ring, oh i understand now, will modify it with explanation shortly. Thanks

Comment: Printing the same element of `list2` more than once is buggy, even though the OP didn't explicitly mention that they wanted the matching lines to be printed once & once only.

Answer (score 1):

To check every element in `list2` you have to loop over every element of that list. For each of those elements you have to check if it is a part of any element in `list1`.

```
for line in list2:
    if any(value in line for value in list1):
        print(line)
```