# How to remove list of words from a list of strings?

Tags: python

```
list1=['water', 'analog', 'resistance', 'color', 'strap','men', 'stainless', 'timepiece','brown','fast']

list2=['water resistant','water','red strap','digital and analog','analog', 'men', 'stainless steel']
```

So that output will  be

```
list=['water resistant','red strap','digital and analog','stainless steel']
```

Comment: and you also want to remove the `**`

Comment: you only want to remove whole matches? have you tried anything for doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get difference from 2 lists. Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305164/get-difference-from-2-lists-python)

Comment: This is a follow on question from http://stackoverflow.com/q/32241949/4014959

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use set operations:

```
list(set(list2) - set(list1))
```

Possible result:

```
['red strap', 'digital and analog', 'stainless steel', 'water resistant']
```

If you want to preserve the order you could do the following:

```
s = set(list1)

[x for x in list2 if x not in s]
```

Result:

```
['water resistant', 'red strap', 'digital and analog', 'stainless steel']
```

Comment: As per my view he also want to remove `**`

Comment: @VigneshKalai It was an formatting issue for SO. I'm sure the OP doesn't have any stars in his code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set` for this. Also with `set` you won't have any item duplicated.

Here is output from Python Shell

```
>>> set1 = set(list1)
>>> set2 = set(list2)
>>> set1
set(['brown', 'timepiece', 'color', 'stainless', 'men', 'resistance', 'fast', 'strap', 'water', 'analog'])
>>> set1-set2
set(['brown', 'timepiece', 'color', 'stainless', 'resistance', 'fast', 'strap'])
>>> set2-set1
set(['red strap', '**water resistant**', '**stainless steel**', '**digital and analog**'])
>>> for each in (set2-set1):
        print each

red strap
**water resistant**
**stainless steel**
**digital and analog**
>>> list3 = list(set2-set1)
>>> list3
['red strap', '**water resistant**', '**stainless steel**', '**digital and analog**']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to

1. remove `*` from `List2` items
2. elements not in `list1`

Try:

```
>>> list = [x.replace('*', '') for x in list2 if x not in list1]
>>> list
['water resistant', 'red strap', 'digital and analog', 'stainless steel']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way. Iterate through a list of list1 words which are in list2, then use the iterator to remove words. This does not work for repeated words.

```
>>> for s in [a for a in list1[:] if a in list2[:]]:
...    list2.remove(s)
... 
>>> list2
['water resistant', 'red strap', 'digital and analog', 'stainless steel']
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: What could make those 2 lines of code any clearer? Maybe say that it's a "list comprehension" so that someone who does not recognise the syntax can look it up? But the first time I saw one my thoughts were "awesome" and after playing with it a bit, "does what it says on the tin".